# Which is the best way to render large number of geometries in three js?

Tags: three.js

Initially when I start my three.js based application there are very few cubes (less than 50) and they are rendered withing no time. But **as number of cubes increase the rendering time increases.**
When I reach 150 cubes with each having texture on all six sides.
It takes long time (3 to 5 minutes) to render the scene.
**Once the scene is rendered I want to add/remove individual cubes, without rendering the whole scene again.**

I have gone through similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806529/threejs-webgl-most-performant-way-for-just-cubes).
But using this technique has following disadvantage:

It won’t be possible to move the merged objects independently from each other. Or you can no more remove or add a object without recomputing the whole geometry.

**How do I solve this issue ?**
Note : I am using WebGL Renderer

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well, no?

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html

Code seemed sane too, has the cubes as separate objects. Though perhaps you mean that need more..

I edited the example to do 1000 cubes for me now, am getting 40fps on this laptop with intel hd 4000 -- not bad I'd say!

Comment: That example does not use textures on cubes. So it might be faster.

Comment: True. I'm not sure if using a texture atlas makes a difference when have many with different textures.